# Synchronized keyword in Java: no matter the number of writing threads... it only really matters if the operation is atomic or not

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I often read statements like:

"Use Synchronized when your variables will get read and written to by multiple threads"

Source:

https://jorosjavajams.wordpress.com/volatile-vs-synchronized/

I don't agree with that and I think it should be changed with:

"Use Synchronized when there is a non-atomic operation"

This is my demonstration:

The thread 1 has the following code:

```
valueX = 10;
```

The thread 2 has the following code:

```
valueX = 5;
```

It doesn't matter if we have a "synchronized" block or not, as one of the two will win anyway. Even with a critical section we don't know which one come first to get the lock.

Here I think it was ok not to use a "synchronized" block, as they were atomic operations.

The following is a very different case:

The thread 1 has the following code:

```
valueX++;
```

The thread 2 has the following code:

```
valueX--;
```

Here we need a "synchronized" block as value++ is non-atomic as it could be written as:

```
int tmp = valueX;
valueX = tmp + 1;
```

My question is: am I right in saying this? If not, could you demonstrate why I'm wrong?

Comment: "I often read statements...", when you stick to reliable sources you don't need to read so many badly formulated statements. A blog by a random developer is not something you should just *trust*. Even some tutorial sites are filled with terrible advice.

Comment: If `valueX` is `volatile`, then yes the first code would work...sort of. Visibility would be guaranteed, but you'd get a lost update. That's not something you'd really have in *working* code though.

Comment: yes Kayman, I forgot to mention but valueX in the first case would be volatile. What do you mean by lost update? Think about the first case in that way: thread one set a switch off and thread 2 set it on.... what's the point of a synchronized block here, even if both of them are writing?

Comment: Imagine it this way, you paint a wall green and I paint it blue right after. That's a lost update (and a waste of time). Synchronized would not be needed there, but one could argue that neither would volatile, as you wouldn't really be very concerned about the the value (i.e. the color of the wall). So the example you're using isn't very good.

Comment: Yeah, you are right on the fact my example is not very good... but my purpose was just  to proof the initial statement in my post was false (from the linked blog). So, if only exist one example that disproof the statement, the statement cannot be true.

Comment: The linked article make also a distinction between having only 1 thread writing and then according to the author synchronized is not necessary; or having more than 1, in which case synchronized is required. For me the only distinstion instead is between atomic and non-atomic operations

Comment: The linked article is garbage. Why do you read garbage? He's not an expert in concurrency, he's a guy who claims only 8 years of Java experience. You want to read about concurrency? Check out [his](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) answers.

Comment: Not sure what's the take of that author on this. However I also found a similar take of the one of the blogger in the book "Java 9 Concurrency Cookbook"  by Fernandes Gonzalez. At page 370 he also states: "The volatile keyword only works well when the value of the shared variable is only modified by one thread. If the variable is modified by multiple threads, the volatile keyword doesn't protect you from possible data-race conditions".

Comment: Such as two people running to paint the same wall.

Answer (score 4):

You are wrong.

Synchronization achieves two things: [Mutual exclusion][1] and memory visibility. You are correct in saying that the operations you perform are atomic. However, you are wrong in general that there is no guarantee that another thread will see the results of the write operation.

According to the [Java memory model][2], unsynchronized operations performed in a thread will be visible to that thread, but they are not necessarily visible to other threads. Thus, if two threads perform `num++` on the same variable `num`, without synchronization the result can be `num+1` or `num+2`, but with synchronization the result will always be `num+2`. This is not because the operation is not atomic, it is because when one thread performs the increment, there is no guarantee that the other thread will see the results of it. Synchronization guarantees that the effects of a write are visible to other threads.

Similar discussion applies to `volatile` variables: access to volatiles usually include memory barriers that make them visible to other threads immediately.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model

Comment: To add to this, the underlying reason Java has adopted this memory model is that it matches how real CPUs tend to work - writes to memory often stay in cache for a short while; in order for the value to be visible to other threads on other cores, the CPU has to perform its cache coherency protocol, which has large costs.